# How can I replace the certain part of a value with something I want in sql?

Tags: sql-server

Lets say that I have 100 names starting Ad.For example "Adam".
I want sql to find all the values starting with Ad and replace "Ad" with "Fo" just in one attempt for all 100 names.Plese if someone know I would be very glad to hear answers.Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried? Why didn't it work?

Comment: Which part of this are you having trouble with? Finding rows starting with Ad? Replacing Ad with Fo? Something else?

Comment: Both finding and replacing

Comment: İ only need syntax for doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `REPLACE` function.  Just a sample I'm building a temp table of names, filling it, and then performing the replace.

```
CREATE TABLE #theNames
 (
    the_name VARCHAR(50)
 );

 INSERT INTO #theNames(the_name) SELECT 'Adam';
 INSERT INTO #theNames(the_name) SELECT 'Bob';
 INSERT INTO #theNames(the_name) SELECT 'Adnan';
 INSERT INTO #theNames(the_name) SELECT 'Adisson';
 INSERT INTO #theNames(the_name) SELECT 'Larry';
 INSERT INTO #theNames(the_name) SELECT 'Seymour';

PRINT 'Before change';
SELECT * FROM #theNames;

UPDATE
    t
SET
    t.the_name = REPLACE(t.the_name, 'Ad', 'Fo')
FROM
    #theNames t
WHERE
    t.the_name LIKE 'Ad%';

PRINT 'After change';
SELECT * FROM #theNames;
DROP TABLE #theNames;
```

Comment: Oh,that is the best answer thanks

Comment: @AlisahibQadimov - Best?  Hardly, it depends on your requirements, please don't just believe my answers - we are here to give you ideas.

Comment: @AlisahibQadimov - this will turn `adracadabra` to `ForacFoabra` is that the desired effect? Also both answers look to be missing a `TOP (1)` or some other means to meet that

Answer (score 1):

Just use the STUFF function as follows:

```
Update [tbl] Set [Name]=STUFF([Name], 1, 2, 'Fo')
Where [Name] Like 'Ad%'
```

Comment: What does 1 and 2 stand for ?

Comment: @AlisahibQadimov you obviously can look it up.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: the function description is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)